# 2D Graphic in Windows Universal App

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, win-universal-app

I was thinking about my upcoming school project focused on Windows 10 universal apps and I ran into very interesting experiment : 
https://www.chromeexperiments.com/experiment/stochasticity

I want to work on something very similiar or achieve similar level of animation in metro universal application writen in Csharp. I have never worked with any sort of animation or 2d graphics while writing WUA.

Can somebody direct me into right way to start with this ? What are your recommendation, is this even possible..any particular sample codes  ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2D raster graphics take a look at [Win2d](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/win2d/). Win2d is a Windows Runtime wrapper over Direct2D and enables high performance 2d rendering similar to what your experiment does with the HTML Canvas. The [CanvasAnimatedControl](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_UI_Xaml_CanvasAnimatedControl.htm) is specifically designed for scenarios like what I think you're looking for.

See the [introduction](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/Introduction.htm) and [quick start](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/QuickStart.htm) on GitHub to get started and for more samples.